# Uploading large mail attachments with MS Graph API, running forever

Tags: python, http, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to upload large attachments (>4 Mb). For that, the documentation suggests the following steps:

Creating a draft message -> starting upload session -> uploading attachment in chunks -> sending the mail

When executing the 3rd step, the code keeps running forever with no response (*only `started` is printed, but not `done`*). If I understand correctly, the `requests.put()` should give me the `NextExpectedRange` bytes to feed into the next `put` iteration. But as I said, it doesnt give me any response. I tried hardcoding the upload process of the chunks as you can see in the code.
In some sites, it was suggested that the chunk length should be dividable by `327680`, thats why I have these 9 iterations. But even trying to upload the whole attachment as one chunk give me the same (no)reaction.

Messing with the header(e.g. taking out the `Content-Length`) gives me an `InvalidContentRange` error, changing `put` to `post` or the `Content-Type`gives me the same (no)reaction.

Needless to say, I have all required permissions.

Would appreciate any kind of help :)

```
#1. create draft
payload=json.dumps({       
"subject":subject,
"importance":"Low",
"body":{               
   "contentType":"Text",
   "content":content},
 "toRecipients":setup_recipients(recipients),
#"ccRecipients":setup_cc_recipients(ccrecipients)  
                })
 mail_data_draft = requests.post(url=ms_graph_endpoint_draft, data=payload, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token'], 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
 message_id=json.loads(mail_data_draft.text)["id"]
            
 #2. creating upload session with message id
            upload_session_endpoint="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + email_account +"/messages/"+message_id+"/attachments/createUploadSession"
            up_session_payload= json.dumps({
                "AttachmentItem":{
                    "attachmentType":"file",
                    "name":attachmentName,
                    "size": contentSize                    
                }
            })
            upload_session_info= requests.post(url=upload_session_endpoint, data=up_session_payload, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token'], 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
            opaque_url =json.loads(upload_session_info.text)["uploadUrl"]
            next_expected_range=json.loads(upload_session_info.text)["nextExpectedRanges"][0]
            
            #####################################################################Tested till here 
            #3. uploading attachment

            #problem
            print("started")
           
            requests.put(url=opaque_url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length':'327680','Content-Range':'bytes 0-327679/3232962'})
            requests.put(url=opaque_url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length':'327680','Content-Range':'bytes 327680-655359/3232962'})
            requests.put(url=opaque_url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length':'327680','Content-Range':'bytes 655360-983039/3232962'})
            requests.put(url=opaque_url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length':'327680','Content-Range':'bytes 983040-1310719/3232962'})
            requests.put(url=opaque_url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length':'327680','Content-Range':'bytes 1310720-1638399/3232962'})
            requests.put(url=opaque_url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length':'327680','Content-Range':'bytes 16383400-1966079/3232962'})
            requests.put(url=opaque_url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length':'327680','Content-Range':'bytes 1966080-2293759/3232962'})
            requests.put(url=opaque_url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length':'327680','Content-Range':'bytes 2293760-2621439/3232962'})
            requests.put(url=opaque_url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length':'327680','Content-Range':'bytes 2621440-2949119/3232962'})
            requests.put(url=opaque_url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length':'283842','Content-Range':'bytes 2949120-3232961/3232962'})

            print("done")
            # sending draft
            global ms_graph_endpoint
            ms_graph_endpoint="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + email_account +  "/messages/"+message_id+"/send"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Apparently I never told it which exact bytes to upload ^^

Comment: If someone has a similar problem and needs the "solution", let me know.

Comment: Please provide the detailed and explained solution.